# Variable height for rows of dataGrid in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5

Hi guys i am creating a popup of a textarea though which i am storing my notes in a data grid. The Code for the data grid is given below.

Now when i add the note IT fits in one of the rows. Now all the rows have same size. I want to make the size variable so that the text fits in each row. For big text notes the height of rows should be greater so that no scroll needed. similarly when the data is small then the height should be small

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid x="0" y="231" width="872" height="273" fontSize="12" id="dgRecentNotes" horizontalGridLineColor="#01030B" dataProvider="{patientProfile.notes}" horizontalGridLines="true"   variableRowHeight="true">
                        <mx:columns>
                            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Recent Notes" dataField="noteText" sortCompareFunction="date_sortCompareFunc" resizable="true">
                                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                                        <fx:Component>
                                            <mx:HBox>
                                                <mx:Text width="100%"  height="100%" text="{(data.createdOn.getMonth()+1)+'/'+data.createdOn.getDate()+'/'+data.createdOn.getFullYear()+' ('+((data.createdOn.getHours()+1) >9 ? (data.createdOn.getHours()+1) : '0' + (data.createdOn.getHours()+1) )+' : ' + ((data.createdOn.getMinutes()+1) >9 ? (data.createdOn.getMinutes()+1) : '0' + (data.createdOn.getMinutes()+1) ) +')' +'\n'+data.noteText}"/>
                                            </mx:HBox>
                                        </fx:Component>
                                    </mx:itemRenderer>
                            </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
                        </mx:columns>
                    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set property `variableRowHeight="true"` for your datagrid and set property `wordWrap="true"` for your datagrid column.
[Refer this blogpost](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/07/23/creating-multi-line-data-grid-rows-with-variable-row-heights/)

Comment: variableRowHeight="true" is already set and i have used wordwrap for column too but didn't work

Comment: you are using itemRenderer so text is displaying in `<mx:Text/>` just give static width to your datagrid column and  100% for Hbox. I dont know exactly.. it may work...(why you are using HBox within item renderer?)

Comment: leave everything as is. just do not use HBox ant your text will fitt.

Comment: As mentioned by 'grass' please remove hbox and it will work. 'variablerowheight' and 'wordwrap' wont work for any flex containers(like Accordion, Box, Canvas, Form, FormItem, LayoutContainer, Panel, PanelItemBase, Tile, ViewStack) renderers

Comment: @ kbgn27 But i have mentioned for datagrid and datagrid column withot havig itemrenderer. Here in this case `<mx:Text/>` displays muliline text so no need of Hbox and setting wordWrap.